# How to print all posts of a given post-type (CPT) in a given webpage?

Tags: custom-post-types

I use latest WordPress and I went to [GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/) and created a new custom post type named "book_pages". I pasted the output in the end of my `functions.php`. The post-type is available and I can work with it in my site.

I then went to "pages" and added a new page named "all book pages".

I'd like to show trimmed version of all nodes of the "book_pages" CPT under "all book pages".

It should be seem like this:

[image]

---

Basically I need just the headline of each webpage to appear in each box under "All book pages" (and each box will link to the relevant **book_page**).

I'll further style the boxes with CSS.

But I only need to know how to actually print all nodes of my "book_pages" CPT in the "All book pages" page.

### Notes:

- **You likely noticed that in this book, each page is actually a chapter-page.**

Comment: I think you can use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function. Use `book_pages` as `post_type` parameter.

Comment: This is a rather unusual way to achieve your goal. When you create a CPT, you can have it automatically create an archive, which is similar to Post Categories in that it typically shows the link, title, and sometimes excerpt of a group of posts within the category. You can set the URL of the archive to whatever you want it to be when you register the CPT.

Comment: @WebElaine I might miss that but **how do you print** the archive inside a given webpage? I'ld like to print such archive as you mention, directly inside the "All books page" page, and then style with CSS (because if it'll give me the heading and the entire element representing a webpage is anchored to it's book_page than that's fine for me).

Comment: [Template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview). You can copy `archive.php` to `archive-book_pages.php` and modify the content (display only post title with link). Archive page will replace your "All books page".

Comment: @nmr this would require me to use a sub-theme otherwise the new file would be deleted in a theme update right? I hate sub-themes, and I don't want to change file permissions. Is there no GUI approach in this case?

Comment: The generic `archive.php` file in your current theme most likely already has a loop to output the list of individual CPTs. Try setting up the CPT to have an archive, set its permalink, visit your settings > permalinks page to make sure the rewrite rules flush, and then go to the archive URL to see how it looks. If you want to change how it looks, yes, you'll need to child theme it. .Even to do your original idea of displaying the CPT archive within a Page, you'll have to add code, which is normally done through a child theme.

Comment: That's right. You have created CPT modifying the `functions.php` file. Why not create a additional archive file for CPT? If you use shortcode or `get_posts()` you also need to modify theme files.

Comment: Oh sorry, yet, it's in `functions.php` as well, maybe I should just use a plugin because I don't work with subthemes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) to get posts of a particular type, then use a for loop to print out links, titles, etc as required.

Maybe put this in a custom template for your "All book pages" page. [More info on templates here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

Example:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    "post_type"=>"book_pages",
    "post_status"=>"publish",
    "posts_per_page"=>-1 
));

if ($posts && count($posts)>0) 
{
    global $post;
    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title(); //prints out the title of this post
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see a small update in the question.

Comment: @Ben thanks, from what I can see this answer still fits - if it's not hitting the mark for you could you elaborate on the requirements? The way to show posts inside another post is either this with a custom template, or using an archive as suggested in the comments.

Comment: You could also create an shortcode with a query like that from @jammypeach.

Comment: Putting a query with an array is best for me as I hate creating sub-themes. I should learn how a query can be implemented inside a shortcode.