# How to write a query-function as a query-shortcode?

Tags: wp-query, functions, loop, shortcode

I ask this question as a follow-up to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312795/how-to-print-all-posts-of-a-given-post-type-cpt-in-a-given-webpage).

I have this query-function in `functions.php` but AAMOF I don't want to change `functions.php` at all (besides for CPTs).

I'd like to print the same data directly from WP GUI via shortcode.

How should a `functions.php` query-function be translated into a query-shortcode?

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    "post_type"=>"book_pages",
    "post_status"=>"publish",
    "posts_per_page"=>-1 
));

if ($posts && count($posts)>0) 
{
    global $post;
    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title(); //prints out the title of this post
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

Comment: There isn't a shortcode that does this. You would need to make it, but that would involve changing functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

A [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) is essentially a trigger that leads to execution of a piece of code in you `functions.php` file. The only real difference with the code you already have is you don't print the result immediately, but return it from the function. Also, `get_posts` is not the preferred way to do multiple loops, as you can see in [the first paragraph in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Better use [`wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) directly. Like this:

```
add_shortcode ('wpse312883', 'wpse312883_query_shorcode' );

function wpse312883_query_shorcode () {
  $all_post_titles = "";
  $args = (array(
    "post_type"=>"book_pages",
    "post_status"=>"publish",
    "posts_per_page"=>-1 
    ));
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
      $all_post_titles .= get_the_title();
      }
    }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $all_post_titles;
  }
```

No, if you include [wpse312883] in your post content in the GUI you will get a list of post titles. You may want to add some html to `$all_post_titles` depending on how you want to format the result.